# Solving Equation for a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve an equation for an unknown variable(y), I am using the below. However it is taking lot of time, I have read some article about using scipy.optimize to speed it, but not sure how to. Any help will be appreciated:

```
from sympy import Eq, var, solve
var('y')    
eq = Eq(((5/(1+((.0025+y)/2)))**2) + ((5/(1+((.0027+y)/2)))**4) + ((105/(1+((.003+y)/2)))**6),104.90)

solve(eq)
```

Comment: What you describe and the code don’t quite match. `sympy` is used for symbolic computation, while `scipy.optimize` will find the value of the root(s) for you. Do you want an equation for the solution or the value itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a numeric solution, you can use `brentq`

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq

f = lambda y: ((5/(1+((.0025+y)/2)))**2) + ((5/(1+((.0027+y)/2)))**4) + ((105/(1+((.003+y)/2)))**6)-104.90

res = brentq(f, 0, 1E8)
```

Comment: Thanks Jacques, however it does not seems to give me the correct value for y. I am interested in solving the following expression for the value of y. $104.90 = $5 / (1 +(2.5% + y) / 2) ^ (2 x 1) + $5 / (1 +(2.7% + y) / 2) ^ (2 x 2) + $105 / (1 +(3% + y) / 2) ^ (2 x 3)

Comment: The equation in your question is wrong then 2.5% = 0.025 != 0.0025

Comment: My bad :(, Thanks for pointing it out, this works as expected.

Comment: By the way I noticed there is no accepted answers on your profile yet. You can read about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer